# How to study for university level math olympiads and competitions?

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, math-contests

I participated in some high-school-level math competitions, but I never invested much of my time in them at that time, something that I regret immensely.

Now that I am an engineering grad student, I want to do something about it and grab the opportunities to compete in college-level math competitions. But, I am having a hard time finding free materials to prepare for them, online. I found a lot of high-school-level resources, but haven't had much luck in finding college-level resources.

I know I'm already asking for a lot of help, but I'm poor in a country where the dollar is really expensive. So if possible (I know it might not be possible), please help me find only free resources for preparation.

Comment: Could you tell us which examinations you want to study for? You could get old questions for those examinations--but they are not cheap. The book for the Putnam exams 1985-2000 costs $53.36 at Amazon.com.

Comment: I believe the site https://artofproblemsolving.com/ has a section for those preparing for contests.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I did not know college-level math olympiads existed, thanks for pointing to William Lowell Putnam Mathematical Competition.

Comment: @RustyCore: You are welcome. I participated in one Putnam exam, long ago, but it was not a good day for me (I didn't feel good) and I think I did fairly poorly. I do not remember any of the questions.

Comment: With acknowledgement to @RoryDaulton - there is an archive for the [Putnam Math Competition](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/). I believe this is exactly what you requested. Free. Let us know if you have trouble accessing.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Wow, what a great find! That archive does not go back to the exam that I took back in 1976 but that is a really great resource. You should put that as an answer--it does answer the question and I would upvote it. (It's a shame this question is off-topic for this site, though.)

Comment: @Rory Daulton: I believe all the older Putnam exams have been published in *American Mathematical Monthly* issues appearing a few months after the exams took place. Certainly the 1976 exam was (I've gotten this journal since January 1974), and all throughout the 1960s and 1970s. I'm not sure whether ALL earlier exams were published, but I suspect they were. I'm surprised that all the exams are not freely available on the internet, as I thought otherwise.

Comment: I guess the question is consensus offtopic for the site but it seems we were able to help anyway if you scroll through the comments. Good luck to you @JoãoVictor.

Comment: Hmm. To me, the question seems on-topic. Self-education is education. He is not asking how to solve a math problem. He is asking how to learn more about certain kinds of math. (math.se has been around a lot longer than this site, so it's not surprising that some questions which may fit better here have been answered there.)

Comment: @SueVanHattum - the reason it was closed was certainly wrong. I don’t know for sure that Math.SE would have welcomed this one either. The question was well tagged, reference-request, but 5 members is all it takes. I’m on the fence, hesitating to answer, but sneaking in a solution for OP.

Comment: JoãoVictor - You can also download the entire book [The William Lowell Putnam Math Competition 1985-2000](http://www.cms.zju.edu.cn/UploadFiles/AttachFiles/20108232376816.pdf). Note: the copywrite page offers “Reproduction. The work may be reproduced by any means for educational and scientific purposes without fee or permission with the exception of
reproduction by services that collect fees for delivery of documents.” I need to state this because of the abundance of online pirated books. (I don't expect this will be reopened, so adding this, now)

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Now that the question is reopened, can you talk more about artofproblemsolving in an answer?

Answer (score 3):

With acknowledgement to @RoryDaulton - there is an archive for the [Putnam Math Competition](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/). I believe this is exactly what you requested. Free. Let us know if you have trouble accessing.

You can also download the entire book [The William Lowell Putnam Math Competition 1985-2000](http://www.cms.zju.edu.cn/UploadFiles/AttachFiles/20108232376816.pdf). Note: the copywrite page offers “Reproduction. The work may be reproduced by any means for educational and scientific purposes without fee or permission with the exception of reproduction by services that collect fees for delivery of documents.” I need to state this because of the abundance of online pirated books.